# error installing program (xournal++ in ubuntu 16)

Tags: software-installation

I just installed ubuntu 16 and want to install xournall++. I get some errors when I run

`autoreconf && ./configure && make`:

```
checking for PACKAGE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.18.3 libglade-2.0 >= 2.6.4 glib-2.0 >= 2.32.0 gthread-2.0 >= 2.4.0 librsvg-2.0 >= 2.14.0 zlib fontconfig lcms) were not met:

No package 'libglade-2.0' found
No package 'librsvg-2.0' found
No package 'lcms' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS
and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear about what you are missing:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.18.3 libglade-2.0 >= 2.6.4 glib-2.0 >= 2.32.0 gthread-2.0 >= 2.4.0 librsvg-2.0 >= 2.14.0 zlib fontconfig lcms) were not met:

No package 'libglade-2.0' found
No package 'librsvg-2.0' found
No package 'lcms' found
```

You need to install the missing packages to go on with the process.

---

As a side note, you should keep in mind the following information provided on the [official Xournal++ page](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp):

> At the moment, Xournal is very stable software **while Xournal++ is not.** If you want stability, **you might be more interested in the original Xournal project**

Further:

> At the moment compiling Xournal++ from source is tricky business. You should therefore first visit the wiki in order to see if there is a known working guide for your system: [Xournal++ Wiki](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/wiki).

Finally, the wiki links to [official pre-built packages](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/releases).

Comment: I have installed libglade-2.0, but My computer outputs the same error. The other two packages will not install. The xournalpp wiki is outdated. I would really like the xournalpp because the stable version of xournal are missing something functions I would like to use

Comment: I have now followed some of the instructions for ubuntu installation in the wiki manual despite the outdated note and managed to get some of the packages to work. Now the only thing missing is the lcms package. there are several packages like lcms2 etc. but I dont think it works. any fixes?

Comment: What missing features? For lcms, did you try or are you supposing it won't work? I understand the wiki might be outdated, but also the program does not seem very actively developed.